# Exception in OrmLite: Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Our code has a SqlExpression, which at its bare minimum is something like:

```
var q = db.From<Users>();

q.Where(u => u.Age == 25);

totalRecords = db.Scalar<int>(q.ToCountStatement());
```

q.ToCountStatement() generates the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users" WHERE ("Age" = @0)
```

However, db.Scalar() throws an exception: Must declare the scalar variable "@0". This has started occurring in recent versions (tested in 4.0.54). The same code was working fine until v4.0.50. I've checked the release notes, but couldn't find a related change.

Even passing a parameter throws the same exception:

```
totalRecords = db.Scalar<int>(q.ToCountStatement(), 25);
```

Is it a bug, or my oversight?

Secondly, is it possible to get `q.ToCountStatement()` to generate a more optimized query with `COUNT(Age)` or `COUNT([PrimaryKey])` instead of `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that OrmLite defaults to parameterized queries you also need to provide the queries db parameters when executing a query (if you've specified any params), e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Users>().Where(u => u.Age == 25);
var count = db.Scalar<int>(q.ToCountStatement(), q.Params);
```

You can also use OrmLite's explicit `Count()` API's, e.g:

```
db.Count<User>(x => x.Age == 25);
```

Or with a typed SqlExpression:

```
var q = db.From<User>().Where(x => x.Age == 25);
db.Count(q);
```

Otherwise another way to specify db params is to use an anonymous object, e.g:

```
db.Scalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Age=@age", new { age = 25});
```

Comment: How would you deal with this scenario where you do not know what params have been added and your query expression has been built up dynamically?

Comment: @James I don't understand the question the first answer shows using a typed SQL Expression, I've also updated my answer to show using OrmLite's explicit Count APIs whilst the last example shows using parameterized SQL.

Comment: Sorry - I found what I needed: conn.Scalar<int>(query.ToCountStatement(), query.Params);